# Is there an error in this Dream.In.Code tutorial for making a file explorer?

Tags: android

I came across the tutorial here:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/

In the tutorial, find this line (use ctrl+f on the browser):

> v = vi.inflate(id, null);

Shouldn't this line be v=vi.inflate(R.layout.file_view,null) instead?

The first parameter to the inflate method must be resource right?

Answer (score -1):

id is getting set to the resource id of a text view it looks like, in the constructor.

```
public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Option>{
    .
    .
    id = textViewResourceId;
    .
    .
}
```

Im not familiar with that site, and I did not test their code but on the surface it seems like at least that portion of it should not be a problem.